# NHibernate and code first

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Do you use SchemaExport and SchemaUpdate in real applications? Initially, you create model and then generate schema? Does it work? Or, you use it only for tests...

Usually, I create db (using visual studio database project) and then mappings and persistent classes or EF entities using designer. But now, I want to try code first approach with Fluent NHibernate.

I have researched SchemaExport and SchemaUpdate and found some issues. For example, update doesn't delete db objects, creates not null columns like nullable if table exists, doesn't generate primary key on many-to-many tables and so on. It mean that I have to recreate db very often. But, what's about data? And, how to deploy changes to production db and so on...

I want to know do you really use code first and SchemaExport(SchemaUpdate) in your applications? May be you can give me some advices...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use SchemaUpdate in production. It is safe precisely because it never does destructive operations like deleting columns. However, it is not a comprehensive solution for updating your database. If you use it you will still have to supplement it with script to update your schema to do things like deleting (as you mention), indexes, changing column type, adding table data, etc. But SchemaUpdate covers the 90% case for me.

The only downside I've discovered is that over time it seems to occasionally add duplicate foreign-key constraints to my table.

One more thing: you should run SchemaUpdate manually from a build tool, not your app itself. It is *not safe* to give your application the rights to modify your db schema!

Answer (score 4):

I use SchemaUpdate/SchemaExport for rapid evolution of my model, but they are not a replacement for a database migration tool. As you mention, data cannot be migrated in a sensible manner in many cases. The tool does not have enough context. (e.g. How can you automatically migrate a FullName column to FirstName/LastName?) I answered a similar question here where I discuss db migration tools in the context of NHibernate.

[NHibernate, ORM : how is refactoring handled? existing data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038601/nhibernate-orm-how-is-refactoring-handled-existing-data)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use these in real applications; I do.

Of course, almost all the work happens in that first go. My practice has been to create a separate project that references the mappings in my main project assembly and handles database creation and the initial data import, if any.

Once the project is in production, I usually unload that project from the solution, but keep it around for reference or if I ever need to switch from create scripts to update scripts.

As for the way NHibernate creates the database, you have to do a little more specification in your Fluent mappings than you otherwise might. I like to specify null/not null, foreign key constraint names, etc. to have maximum control over the way the database gets created.

I don't think you'd ever want to use automapping in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Just with any generating code whether it be poco generation from a tool or database generation as in your question, it will probably get you 80% of the way there. From there it would be wise to tweak it the other 20% to add your indexes and any other performance tweaks to get it just right.