# How to Manage and Deploy Schema in ASP.NET MVC Applications (w/ NHibernate)

Tags: database, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-3, web-deployment

With an ASP.NET MVC3 application, **how do I deploy the database into production, and how do I manage the schema changes?**

When I'm developing my application, I see an aspnetmvc.mdf (and .ldf) file in app_data. This has the `aspnet._` tables, and also my tables (which I hand-created in SQL Server Express). This file is 10MB, and it doesn't seem to me that I should simply upload it to my production machine.

Should I instead keep schema (and seed data) changes in a .SQL file and (somehow) run them on the server? Should I use NHibernate's methods for auto-generating tables? (If so, what about the ASP.NET standard tables?)

What's the best way to manage this? Ideally, I'd like something like LiquiBase or Rails' DB migrations, where I can isolate changes and run them in isolation. But I've never put a from-scratch ASP.NET MVC site into production, so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thoughts on NHibernate's Schema Update are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216708/nhibernate-and-code-first/4216835#4216835).

There is no one right solution, but SchemaUpdate can get you about 90% of the way there. For the other 10%, I currently use hand-written sql files (named by the date they were created), but there are other, more sophisticated options (such as RedGates SqlCompare or the data tools built into some versions of Visual Studio).

Comment: I don`t really like that SchemaUpdate is non-destructive. But +1 becuse this leads me strongly towards the class of solutions.